# how to get data from CURL post output

Tags: json

i am posting data through CURL
and am getting output according to that data
now i want to parse that output

the out put am getting is

```
a:3:{s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:3:"msg";s:32:"Transaction Fetched Successfully";s:19:"transaction_details";a:1:{i:100000001;a:2:{s:8:"mihpayid";s:9:"Not Found";s:6:"status";s:9:"Not Found";}}}
```

here the value of status is Not Found
i want to save the status value in a php variable how i can do that ?

Comment: Is there no documentation for that API, specifying the output format and how to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but that looks php serialization.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

If you are consuming from php you can call unserialize.

If you are consuming from javascript there are some existing implementations. I found one here: http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/ (since the question is tagged as json this might be what you wanted)

There are also quite a few implementations in various languages/technologies for deserializing this format which can be easily found if needed.